# MailApp.sendEmail triggered by 'on edit' and Browser.msgBox(..., Browser.Buttons.YES_NO) not in outbox

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using MailApp.sendEmail triggered by 'on edit' and Browser.msgBox(..., Browser.Buttons.YES_NO) but since last Thursday (2019-04-18 where I noticed it) the outgoing emails are not visible in the 'sent' folder anymore, despite they were all the time before.

Nothing has been changed on the script and nothing has been changed on the spreadsheet. The emails got sent but are not visible in the outbox. Executing MailApp.sendEmail in debugging mode creates emails in the outbox.

edit 20190426: Same issue with triggered on form submit

Comment: if you search for them can you find them?

Comment: No, I only know that those emails get sent because I get replies to those emails and because I had sent one to one of my own email accounts.

Answer (score 0):

As of 01/05/2019 10:58 CET it is back to normal. Emails sent via spreadsheet triggers are visible in the outbox again. Nothing has been changed on the script or spreadsheet.